# What is the best way to count absolute array length in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering, when you use `array.length` it gets the last index value and adds one.  What if you have an array, that is defined this way for some reason:

```
    var myArray2 =[];
    myArray2[10]='x';
    myArray2[55]='x';
```

What is the absolute best way to get the true length of this Array? Something that would return 2 as the value.

I was thinking something like this, but not sure if there was already a method for this, or if there is a faster implementation.

```
Array.prototype.trueLength= function(){
    for(var i = 0,ctr=0,len=myArray2.length;i<len;i++){
        if(myArray2[i]!=undefined){
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    return ctr;        
}
console.log(myArray2.trueLength());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) only walks through existing indexes, so you can do:

```
var length = myArray2.reduce(function(sum) {
    return sum+1;
}, 0);
```

"But Uncle Zirak! `reduce` killed my parents!" Don't worry, young one, we can use `Array.prototype.filter`!

```
var length = myArray2.filter(function(item, idx) {
    return idx in myArray2;
}).length;
```

"All this array stuff is boring!" Well, whadya think of this!?

```
Object.keys(myArray2).length;
```

"But...but...but Zirak!!!! We're Amish, we don't have ECMAScript 5 yet!" Have no fear, Zirak is here!

```
for (var length = 0, i = 0; i < myArray2.length; i++) {
    if (i in myArray2) {
        length += 1;
    }
}
```

But at times like this, one has to wonder: Why do all that and defy the purpose of the array, a structured construct, instead of using something else fit for its purpose?

Comment: Nice. Of course, you'd need an implementation of `Array.prototype.reduce` for IE < 9

Comment: @TimDown Compensated for that (and some more.)

Comment: But Uncle Zirak, I still have to work with old IE. Does that mean I'm Amish?

Comment: @TimDown Just because all apples are fruit, doesn't make all that's a fruit an apple.

Comment: Correct, some fruits can be lemons too!

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through array using `for in`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXDPq/)

```
Array.prototype.trueLength= function(){
  var ctr = 0;  
  for(var i in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    return ctr;        
}
console.log(myArray2.trueLength());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Prototype method :

```
Array.prototype.trueLength= function(){
    var list= [], ctr = 0, array = this;

    for(var i in array) (function(arr) {

        if(array.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            list.push(arr);
            ctr++;
        };


    }(array[i]));

    return {length: ctr, "list": list}
}
```

sample:

```
var myArray2 =[];
    myArray2[10]='44';
    myArray2[55]='55';

// list not undefined 
myArray2.trueLength().list  // ["44", "55"]

// not undefined length list
myArray2.trueLength().length // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
function getArrayPropertyCount(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i in arr) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function TrueArrayLength (myArray2)
{
var TrueLength = 0;    
for ( var i = 0; i < myArray2.length; i++) 
{
    if (i in myArray2) 
    {
        TrueLength += 1;
    }
}

return TrueLength;
}
```

Use this function and get the true array lengths.